# Open doc file is null IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop

I try open .doc file with interop, when I debug code in Visual studio result is a file but I publish web to IIS result is null.
I'm using Windows server 2012 64bit and Microsoft Office 2007.
Why result in IIS return null and solution?

```
 var wordApp = new Application { Visible = false };
 var path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "File\\TestFile.doc";
 object srcPath = path;
 var wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref srcPath);
```

Comment: Code is throwing any exception?

Comment: I added code in question

Comment: maybe path of file is to local drive?

Comment: I would not recommend using the MS Office API for anything running in IIS. MS Office isn't thread safe so you can easily wind up in trouble with multiple users requesting your page at the same time.

Comment: var path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "File\\TestFile.doc";

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the program from the Visual studio then code uses the logged in user to make calls for COM components(Microsoft word). Generally logged in user has permission to execute the calls on the COM component. So code will work in the Visual studio.

When you publish the website into IIS then it uses default user of IIS to make the call to COM component. If that user doesn't have the permission then call fails and throws the exception.
First find out the user that IIS  is using. Add that user to the specific COM component and give the permission to execute the calls.

Comment: I allowed Local Launch and Local Activation in Component Service with user IIS_IUSRS but not work.

Comment: IIS 7.5 runs under the ApplicationPoolIdentity which maps to an account IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationPool(e.g. IISAPPPOOL\DefaultAppPool). This account is a member of IIS_IUSRS user group.
In your code write below line to find out the IIS user.
Environment.UserName.ToString().
Add that user to the Local Launch and Launch Activation permission.

Comment: Try below steps.
1. Start > Run > dcomcnfg (or “mmc -32″ and then add the Component Services snap-in manually if you can’t find the app under step 3)
2. Navigate to Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
3. Locate the MS application giving you trouble (eg: “Microsoft Word 97 – 2003 Document” for Word) Right click > Properties
4. On the security tab: Select Customize under Launch and Activation Permissions and click Edit…
5. Add the account under which the site is running (eg: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool) and assign Local Launch & Local Activation permissions.

Comment: I added user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I faced following exception "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{000209FF-0000-0000C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005
Access is Denied" and it worked with above changes. Are you getting any exception from the code?

Comment: Allow Local Launch and Local Activation in Component Service with user IIS_IUSRS then your exception is remove. But result when open file is null

Answer (score 0):

1. Start > Run > dcomcnfg
2. Navigate to Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
3. Locate to "Microsoft Word 97 – 2003 Document" > Right click > Properties
4. On the security tab: Select all radio to (Use default)